Search is hallucinating badly

So I noticed that there was some changes to search, and I decided to give it a try.
In its current shape and form, its essentially counterproductive, hurts the utility of my site and potentially violates the agreement. I'd note that if there was a similar feature discussed, and I'm misunderstanding that this was it, I'm open to clarification. However I'm not aware of a request for comments for something like this going out apparently network wide in this timeframe
One would note, that the search also generally has the accuracy of a blind knifethrower throwing blunt axes
Aside from, well, being completely broken - there being no prior warning of a network wide feature.
In its current shape and form, its essentially counterproductive, hurts the utility of my site and potentially violates the strike agreement
In addition since it includes a currently broken save as Q&A button, and my site has a no AI policy - users who use this feature, if it works risk getting suspended.
I'd like some clarity on what's going on, why a feature was released without informing moderators or the community, what the intentions are with respect to the future of this, and why a broken feature was released, in a somewhat unfinished state?
Also for all its flaws, I'd like search back please.

I have a standard "is:question intags:mine" search I use to get new questions - search has started producing some nonsense for this which can never be right

Well, it does disclaim that "responses can vary in accuracy" and you could say that "complete and utter bullshit on a different topic" does just barely fall on the accuracy scale ;) Not sure it deserves the name "search" tho.

(Did I miss an announcement or documentation for this feature?)

(don't think so, unless I missed it too. Why are we whispering?)

@RebeccaJ.Stones Lately it seems the order is: release -> people get confused and file bugs -> silence -> "oh, yeah, we released this few days ago" (sometimes accompanied by "we told you half a year ago in an edit to some other meta post")

@user1176409 don't remove the [tag:search] tag, it's vital for, well, searching. You might add additional tags to narrow it down, but we must have that tag for any question that is about search. Thanks.

@ShadowWizard Oops, sorry.

Wait, the AI enhanced search is disappearing? I can’t see it on my device at this moment.

Not working here too.  Maybe it's been deactivated.

Yup, can confirm its dead. It was amusing when it lasted.

Closing this one as I've answered the more direct question of "was the test officially announced". But yeah, should've never happened :)

Yes, I agree. If the community wants to do an experiment on searching, can the popup not shown anytime when we are searching? It is quite annoying, like what @Journeyman Geek says:

One would note, that the search also generally has the accuracy of a blind

Can we dismiss the popup by clicking anything?

Because you are a frequent visitor of ELL, you should know that the actual quote is: … a blind knifethrower throwing blunt axes … grammatically speaking you need a noun or noun phrase after "a blind [what]" I feel in this answer you misunderstood what the issue is/was/will be. It's has very little to do with the pop up, it's the quality of results yielded by the AI tool. EDITED I've now read a post by you, which rejects my reservation.

@Mari-LouA Unfortunately, I really don’t know what does the phrase means, and the whole phrase is edited at the question after I write my answers, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/403290/5

If you're referring to the search string "how do I mine for fish" it is deliberately nonsensical to confuse and trick an AI. If you're referring to "hallucinating" in the title it accuses  Large Language Models of creating false answers, "answers" that come out of thin air and have not been fact checked. If you're referring to "a blind knife thrower" it's a metaphor, it's a blind folded entertainer who throws knives  at his assistant who stands motionless against a wooden panel. If the entertainer uses blunt axes, he's not going to be very successful.
